# Why doesnt JQuery datePicker execute?

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset = "utf-8/">
        <title>Calander</title>
       <script type = "text/javascript" src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>  

<script>
    $('#Date').datepicker();
</script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <label for= "Date"> Date </label>
        <input type = "text" id = "Date" name = "Date"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I run this nothing happens I want the calendar to show up when clicking on textbox. I think it may be because of the format i.e. inncorrect src

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the whole code of including jQuery datepicker.

you can also see here : https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script type="text/javascript">
 
 
  $(function() {
   $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });
 
  
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thankyou for answering but if I copy and paste the code to my IDE and run it on chrome notjing happens just textbox

Comment: I updated the fiddle i think it will help..Thanks! @el mashrafi

Comment: Ohh thankyou it worked can you explain why it didnt prompt earlier?

Comment: there was problem with source path, i had defined instead `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>` to `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>` Thank @elmashrafi

Answer (score 0):

datepicker is not part of jquery but jquery UI. So you should include jqueryUI

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thankyou is there anything I need to download or copy? because after copying and pasting that to my code the calendar still dont pop up

Comment: move
    <script>
    $('#Date').datepicker();
</script>

just before </body>